Status bar is transparent
I have a Flutter application where we have WEB redirection. I need to set the status bar to white or non-transparent.
I want this output.

but when scrolling then it looks like this.

I have written native code for this in swift. Below is my viewDidLoad function.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
            let closeButton = UIButton(type: .system)
                         closeButton.setTitle("Close", for: .normal)
                         closeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: 80, height: 50)
                         closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goBack), for: .touchUpInside)
                         self.view.addSubview(closeButton)
                 
                 
    
                 activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
                         activityIndicator.center = view.center
                         activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                         view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    
            self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    let url123 = appDelegate.paymentUrl
    let url = URL(string: url123)!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    //setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    //self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    //self.webView.uiDelegate = self
}

I have made changes in Info.list as well
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>

but still this is not working
Flutter code.
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.white,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,

  ),
);
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(<DeviceOrientation>[
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
]).then((_) => runApp(configuredApp));

